# Solve the following (logarithmic) function for x

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, logarithms

> $x^{log_{2}x}+16x^{-log_{2}x} = 17$

Looks horrible, I started by removing the exponents:

$e^{ln(x)*log_{2}x}+16e^{-ln(x)*log_{2}x}=17$ | ln()

$ln(x)*log_{2}x-16ln(x)*log_{2}x=ln(17)$

$ln(x)*log_{2}x(1-16)=ln(17)$

$-15ln(x)*log_{2}x=ln(17)$ |:(-15)

$ln(x)*log_{2}x=-\frac{ln(17)}{15}$

And here is the dead end for me, tried several different things I cannot write them all here but nothing lead to a solution. At least it looks better than at the beginning... :D

Is this even the right way to go or there are easier things? And is it possible to somehow

change $ln(x)*log_{2}x$ to something else, something which looks better?

Answer (score 3):

$$x^{ log_{ 2 }x }+\frac { 16 }{ x^{ log_{ 2 }x } } =17\\ { x }^{ 2\log _{ 2 }{ x }  }-17x^{ log_{ 2 }x }+16=0\\ \left( x^{ log_{ 2 }x }-16 \right) \left( x^{ log_{ 2 }x }-1 \right) =0\\ x^{ log_{ 2 }x }=16\Rightarrow \log _{ 2 }{ x^{ log_{ 2 }x } } =\log _{ 2 }{ 16 } \Rightarrow { \left( \log _{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=4\Rightarrow \log _{ 2 }{ x } =\pm 2\Rightarrow { x }_{ 1 }=4,{ x }_{ 2 }=\frac { 1 }{ 4 } \\ x^{ log_{ 2 }x }=1\Rightarrow \log _{ 2 }{ x^{ log_{ 2 }x } } =\log _{ 2 }{ 1 } \Rightarrow { \left( \log _{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }=0\Rightarrow { x }_{ 3 }=1$$

Comment: Battani tyvm too you helped me a lot today, this was the second time now :)
It's very nice to have 2 different solutions in front of me, I will note them both and understand them, tyvm both of you again!

Comment: you are welcome,my pleasure)

Answer (score 2):

let $$y=x^{log_2x}$$

your equation becomes, $$y+\frac{16}y=17$$

solve it, you get two solutions: 1 and 16.

Now it becomes less horrible, $$x^{log_2x}=1 ~or~ 16 $$

This leads to solution $x =1$, $2^2$ and $2^{-2}$

Comment: Wow so easy and short, I had substitution in mind actually but I didn't know what to substitute exactly :P
Tyvm!